# Surface are of a curve $y=\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{6} \right)$ rotated about the $x$ axis.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I'm doing a problem involving finding the surface area of the curve for $y=\sin \left(\frac{\pi x}{6} \right)$, rotated about the $x$ axis, for $[0 < x < 6]$.

I got as far as $\frac{72}{\pi} \int^{\pi/6}_0 \sqrt{1+u^2} du$ with $u=\frac{\pi}{6}\cos(\frac{\pi x}{6})$. I'm not really sure how to precede from this point though.

Comment: Is that $S$ supposed to be an integral symbol?

Comment: Yea. It is. One thing I haven't figured out how to put correctly here yet...

Comment: See this: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a link for math formatting used here.

Comment: To complete the integral, substitute $u=\sinh \theta$

Comment: what does the h at the end of sin mean? Not familiar with sinh.

Comment: It's what's known as a [hyperbolic function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HyperbolicFunctions.html). If you're not familiar with them, you can use a trigonometric substitution of $u=\tan \theta$ instead.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plot of the surface of revolution:

[image]

The area of the surface is given by
$$2\pi\int_0^6\sin\frac{\pi x}{6}\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left[\sin\frac{\pi x}{6}\right]\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x=2\pi\int_0^6\sin\frac{\pi x}{6}\sqrt{1+\frac{\pi^2}{36}\cos^2\frac{\pi x}{6}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
Substituting $u=\frac{\pi}{6}\cos\frac{\pi x}{6}$, so that $\mathrm{d}u=-\frac{\pi^2}{36}\sin\frac{\pi x}{6}\,\mathrm{d}x$, you get the integral you're currently stuck on:
$$-\frac{72}{\pi}\int_{\pi/6}^{-\pi/6}\sqrt{1+u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u=\frac{144}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/6}\sqrt{1+u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
(I believe you made a slight mistake with either the coefficient or the lower limit of the integral here.)

Now, substituting $u=\tan t$, you have that $\mathrm{d}u=\sec^2t\,\mathrm{d}t$, and so the integral is
$$\frac{144}{\pi}\int_0^{\tan^{-1}(\pi/6)}\sqrt{1+\tan^2t}\sec^2t\,\mathrm{d}t=\frac{144}{\pi}\int_0^{\tan^{-1}(\pi/6)}\sec^3t\,\mathrm{d}t$$
The latter integral can be computed in a variety of ways, and the process is described in detail [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed).

Comment: How do you get to the 144/pi and negative gone?

Comment: @windy401 The integrand is symmetric about $u=0$ (i.e. an even function), so $$\int_{-a}^af(u)\,\mathrm{d}u=2\int_0^af(u)\,\mathrm{d}u$$

Comment: Ohh ok thanks..